# java - wait and notify in a non-synchronized block

Tags: java, wait, notify

Sorry for my bad formatting. I am using a notepad to write my programs.

This is a working code. The only question I have is, I have read that notify and wait must be used in a Synchornized block. However, in the following example, wait and notify are not used in a synchronized block and still no error is thrown.

```
class counthrd implements Runnable {

    Thread thrd;
    String x;
    counthrd cnt1;

    counthrd() {
    }
    boolean suspended;
    boolean stopped;

    counthrd(String s, counthrd cnt1) {
        thrd = new Thread(this, s);
        this.cnt1 = cnt1;
        thrd.start();
        x = s;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            System.out.println("Starting " + thrd.currentThread().getName());
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.print(i + "  ");
                if ((i % 10) == 0) {
                    System.out.println();
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
//synchronized(cnt1){
                while (suspended) {
                    System.out.println("going to wait mode");
                    wait();
                    notify();
                }
//}
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    synchronized void suspendme() {
        suspended = true;
        notify();
    }

    synchronized void resumeme() {
        suspended = false;
        notify();
    }
}

class counter {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        counthrd cnt1 = new counthrd();
        counthrd cnthrd1 = new counthrd("thrd 1", cnt1);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("going to wait mode");
        cnt1.suspendme();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("resuming");
        cnt1.resumeme();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work for you? Normally, wait() does not need to be locked, however, notify() does.

Comment: You know, Eclipse is for free. It lets you type the first part of a variable name and come up with the rest. This makes your life easier and lets you use variables with different names than `"thrd"`. It also does the formatting for you.

Comment: so why is my question down rated? it is a genuine question.

Comment: According to [§17.2.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.1), an `IllegalMonitorStateException` is to be thrown in the case where the thread lacks a lock on the subject of the `wait`.

Comment: @veer...thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: @veer Please post this as an answer so that I can upvote it properly.

Comment: @gobernador except it's not an answer, just a comment :p The answer is that he's never actually calling `wait` at all.

Comment: @veer _"The answer is that he's never actually calling `wait` at all."_ So post that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023056/java-wait-and-notify-in-a-non-synchronized-block#comment16045203_12023056). Since `IllegalMonitorStateException` is never thrown, we know that `wait` is never being called.

Notice you have two instances of `counthrd`...

```
counthrd cnt1 = new counthrd();
counthrd cnthrd1 = new counthrd("thrd 1", cnt1);
```

See which instance you're calling `suspendme` and `resumeme` on?

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("going to wait mode");
cnt1.suspendme();
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("resuming");
cnt1.resumeme();
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

`cnt1` is initialized using your no-arg constructor, seen here:

```
counthrd() {
}
```

The point is that `cnt1` never actually starts its own thread. It never does anything, really. `cnthrd1` is the one that starts a thread, as seen here:

```
counthrd(String s, counthrd cnt1) {
    thrd = new Thread(this, s);
    this.cnt1 = cnt1;
    thrd.start();
    x = s;
}
```

The point to make is that `suspended` is an instance field, and not shared between `cnt1` and `cnthrd1`. Modifying `cnt1.suspended` will not cause `cnthrd1` to go into "wait mode". `wait` is never called, and thus the exception is never thrown.

To demonstrate, try calling `suspendme` and `resumeme` on `cnthrd1`, instead... :-)

```
C:\dev\scrap>javac counter.java

C:\dev\scrap>java counter
Starting thrd 1
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
going to wait mode
going to wait mode
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
resuming
```

---

That being said, I figured I'd suggest you do some stuff that your code should be doing.

1. Declare `suspended` as `volatile`. Without some explicit memory ordering guarantees, there's no guarantee when or even *if* `cnthrd1` reads the updated value of `suspended`.
2. Ditch the `cnt1` field and instance; there's no reason for them. Get rid of that empty constructor, too.
3. `Thread.currentThread` is a static method; you don't need to use an instance for it. That all aside, `thrd` is guaranteed to equal `Thread.currentThread` here.
4. `counthrd.x` is equal to `thrd.getName`; why not just use `x` instead?
5. Use some better, more descriptive names. For example, instead of `x`, why not `name`? Instead of `thrd`, why not `thread`? Instead of `counthrd`, why not `CountingThread`?
6. You only need to call `notify` in `resumeme`, not `suspendme`. (in fact, calling `notify` in `suspendme` could accidentally trigger an `InterruptedException` if the thread is sleeping i.e. when `(i % 10) == 0`)
7. You also don't want `notify` in the `while (suspended)` loop. Your `while` loop can actually be turned into an `if` statement, too, now.
8. As previously stated, you need `synchronized (this)` around your code that calls `while`.
9. Avoid doing real logic in the constructor, e.g. `thrd.start()`.
10. `suspend` doesn't need to be `synchronized`. `resume` doesn't need to be `synchronized`, either; only the `wait` and `notify` calls require it.

You can find a modified version of your example that works properly [here](http://ideone.com/LLjey).

Comment: @veer...Thank you so much for taking your time and explaining in detail. I actually wanted to create 2 threads on `counthrd` to interleave the output and I wanted a common reference for these 2 threads to use. So that is why I was trying to create `cnt1` instance. Also in the synchornized block I want to synchronize on this common reference `cnt1` and not on `this` an instance for each thread. Anyways, I found that whatever crazy thing I was trying to do, I still need to use `this` in the synchornized block. I also looked at the modified version. Thanks again.